# "The panda is an endangered species" "Pandas are an endangered species"... Which would be acceptable?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

"A panda is an endangered species".

"Pandas are an endangered species".

"The panda is an endangered species"

"The pandas are an endangered species".

If you want to mention pandas in general, which one is acceptable and natural?

Comment: The first sentence is fair to me. A panda means all pandas.

Comment: @bak1936 - You are wrong. _The panda_ can refer to the whole species, _a panda_ just means an individual animal.

Comment: @KateBunting you are right! The panda refer to the whole species. I give the evidence that the first sentence is appropriate, too. Please, refer to the number 7 of usage of word 'A'  in a dictionary(https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/a)

Comment: @bak1936 - We can say "A panda is _an animal_ with black and white fur", but not "A panda (singular) is _a species_ (plural)."

Comment: @KateBunting I think you are right. I agree with a native speaker. Thanks!!! 'The sea turtle is an endangered species.'(Oxford dictionary)

Comment: It is better to use 'Pandas are an endangered species'.

Answer (score 1):

"A panda is an endangered species" - This is completely wrong, how can one panda be an entire species?

"Pandas are an endangered species" - This is best recommended as "pandas" are plural to represent the entire species

"The panda is an endangered species" - This is also possible, as "panda" is singular but is generic when using "the".

"The pandas are an endangered species" - This is the same meaning as the 2nd sentence.